# Not able to get value using: this.$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val() in JS Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine

Generally, we can use to get INPUT_ELEMENT_ID value using JQuery as:

```
$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val();
```

Which is differ from this code: `this.$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val();` or same to above line of code.

**Reason to post this question:**

I wrote Unit Testing for my backbone application using Jamine.js framework for code coverage.

If my Backbone application's view normally has code:  `$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val();`, then I could easily check the **INPUT_ELEMENT_ID** value.

But If my application's view code has code: `this.$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val();`, I can not check the value of **INPUT_ELEMENT_ID** from Jasmine.js spec file.

(I used Fixtures to get **INPUT_ELEMENT_ID** value from my Jasmine view spec.js file)

Kindly help me, to understand the problem and resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `this` represents DOM object and you need jQuery object, also you find if you thing the input you are looking for is descendant of object being pointed with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val();

used to get value with id .

```
follwoing line is wrong
```

this.$("#{INPUT_ELEMENT_ID}").val();

```
we can write this as
```

$(this).val();

```
   here this is same id or class use in above function .
    e.g:

 $(".word_span ").on("click", function (){
   alert($(this).attr('title')); 
 });
```